# "In instantiation of ... required ... required from here" and "no type named..." in std::stable_sort

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string TmpS;
    cin >> TmpS;
    stable_sort(TmpS[0], TmpS[TmpS.size()]);
}
```

Compiling this code on Compiler Explorer gives me these following errors:

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/algorithm:62,
                 from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of 'void std::__stable_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = char; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:5056:36:   required from 'void std::stable_sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = char]'
<source>:8:16:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:5008:9: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<char>'
 5008 |         _ValueType;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:5010:9: error: no type named 'difference_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<char>'
 5010 |         _DistanceType;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/stl_algo.h:5011:68: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<char>'
 5011 |       typedef _Temporary_buffer<_RandomAccessIterator, _ValueType> _TmpBuf;
      |                                                                    ^~~~~~~
```

I don't understand these errors, presumably it's failing at deducing what type the values and range should be? Googling did not help. Why does the compiler throw these errors and how do I fix my code?

Comment: Don't be discouraged by the truly abysmal error messages. C++ is infamous for its horrible template errors. Generally, when I see a mess of an error like that, I find the line in the stack trace that refers to my code (as opposed to stdlib code) and just look at that line for any glaring problems. In your case, that line is `<source>:8:16: required from here`.

Answer (score 1):

You want `std::sort(TmpS.begin(), TmpS.end());`.

`std::stable_sort(TmpS.begin(), TmpS.end());` would also work, but because you don't provide a custom comparator, it would do the exact same thing as `std::sort`, while being slower (because of the stability guarantee).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the iterators of the start and end point of the string.(To be precise  the portion of the string you want to sort)
So you can use begin() and end() methods here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string TmpS;
    cin >> TmpS;
    stable_sort(TmpS.begin(), TmpS.end());
    cout << TmpS;
}
```

Comment: yes, sorry actually they'll return iterators

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass references to the data, not the values themselves.

```
stable_sort(&TmpS[0], &TmpS[TmpS.size()]);
```